# Changing class from character to integer but retaining all the datas inside

Tags: r, dbi

q7 <- dbGetQuery(conn,
"SELECT TailNum AS TailNum, AVG(ontime.DepDelay) AS avg_delay, ontime.Year AS Year, planes.Year AS yearmade
FROM planes JOIN ontime USING(tailnum)
WHERE ontime.Cancelled = 0 AND planes.Year != '' AND planes.Year != 'None' AND ontime.Diverted = 0 AND ontime.DepDelay > 0
GROUP BY TailNum
ORDER BY avg_delay")

Codes that i have tried:
q7 <- data.frame(
yearmade = q7.yearmade, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

[image]

^ Dataframe

Hi! Basically I would like to create a new column where the Year would subtract the yearmade and be placed into a new column, but before I could do that, I found out that the data I draw from another table into this dataframe shows as character(yearmade), is there any way to change it but retain the original data inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use `as.numeric()` to change `yearmade` into a numeric variable. Then you can simply compute the difference between `Year` and `yearmade`.

I believe this will work for you.

```
set.seed(1)

Year <- 2000:2022
yearmade <- sample(c('2000', '1999', '1998'), length(Year), replace = TRUE)
TailNum <- sample(c('N3738B', 'N3737C', 'N37342'), length(Year), replace = TRUE)
avg_delay <- 1:length(Year)
q7 <- data.frame(TailNum, avg_delay, Year, yearmade)

# compute difference and add to data frame
q7$year_diff <- q7$Year - as.numeric(q7$yearmade)
```

This retains the original data, but introduces a new column `year_diff`.

```
> str(q7)
'data.frame':   23 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ TailNum  : chr  "N3738B" "N3738B" "N3737C" "N3738B" ...
 $ avg_delay: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Year     : int  2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 ...
 $ yearmade : chr  "2000" "1998" "2000" "1999" ...
 $ year_diff: num  0 3 2 4 4 7 8 8 9 11 ...
```

Comment: Would you suggest if I change it to numeric before I pull the data from another table? I tried to use the following codes

q7 <- df$year_diff <- df$Year - as.numeric(df$yearmade)
It is showing me the error of "Error in df$Year : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: I replaced `df` with `q7` for clarity and made it more look like your own data. Cheers!